# Getting an error while creating docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

When I try to create a docker network, I'm getting below errors.

iptables --wait -l FORWARD -o br-31422214d633 -j DOCKER: iptables v1.8.7(nf_tables): RULE_INSERT failed

iptables --wait -l FORWARD -o br-31422214d633 -j DOCKER: iptables v1.8.7(nf_tables): RULE_INSERT failed

DOCKER: iptables v1.8.7(nf_tables): RULE_INSERT failed(invalid argument): rule in chain FORWARD

Can anybody provide some guidance on how to fix this?

OS: RHEL 7
Docker version: 20.10.9

Comment: I never had the issue, but I found some links referring to the issue which you could check and see if any helps:
- https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/927
- https://github.com/tailscale/tailscale/issues/401
- https://serverfault.com/questions/1040781/error-while-creating-docker-network-error-response-from-daemon-failed-to-progr

Comment: i have this is in devcontainer